# TensorFlow - return distinct sub-tensors of multidimensional tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In TensorFlow, the `tf.unique` function can be used to return the distinct elements of a 1-dimensional `Tensor`. How can I get the distinct sub-`Tensor`s along the axis 0 of a higher-dimensional `Tensor`? For example, given the following `Tensor`, the desired `distinct` function would return the specified result:

```
input = tf.constant([
    [0,3],
    [0,1],
    [0,4],
    [0,1],
    [1,5],
    [3,9],
    [3,2],
    [3,6],
    [3,5],
    [3,3]])

distinct(input) == tf.constant([
    [0,3],
    [0,1],
    [0,4],
    [1,5],
    [3,9],
    [3,2],
    [3,6],
    [3,5],
    [3,3]])
```

How can the distinct multidimensional elements be generated for `Tensor`s of any number of dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to look for elements for which a previous sub-`Tensor` along the axis 0 is equal, then filter those out:

1. Use `tf.equal` to get the pairwise equality of the individual axis -1 elements of the input crossed with itself along axis 0.
2. Use `tf.math.reduce_all` to aggregate the pairwise equalities until you have a 2-D equality matrix for the axis 0 elements of the input.
3. Generate an upper-triangular matrix of False values
4. Use that triangular matrix to restrict our equality comparisons to one direction along axis 0.
5. Use `tf.reduce_any` to find which axis 0 elements are equal to any later elements; they are the duplicates that will be removed.
6. Use `tf.math.logical_not` and `tf.boolean_mask` to obtain only the non-duplicate elements of axis 0.

This process is implement in the following Python code, tested in TensorFlow 2.0 beta:

```
def distinct(input:tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    """Returns only the distinct sub-Tensors along the 0th dimension of the provided Tensor"""
    is_equal = tf.equal(input[:,tf.newaxis], input[tf.newaxis,:])
    while len(is_equal.shape) > 2:
        is_equal = tf.math.reduce_all(is_equal, axis=2)
    all_true = tf.constant(True, shape=is_equal.shape)
    true_upper_tri = tf.linalg.band_part(all_true, 0, -1)
    false_upper_tri = tf.math.logical_not(true_upper_tri)
    is_equal_one_way = tf.math.logical_and(is_equal, false_upper_tri)
    is_duplicate = tf.reduce_any(is_equal_one_way, axis=1)
    is_distinct = tf.math.logical_not(is_duplicate)
    distinct_elements = tf.boolean_mask(input, is_distinct, 0)
    return distinct_elements
```

Answer (score 4):

**Without preserving Order**

You can use `tf.py_function` and call `np.unique` to return unique multidimensional tensors along axis=0. Note that this finds the unique rows but does not preserve the order.

```
def distinct(a):
    _a =  np.unique(a, axis=0)
    return _a

>> input = tf.constant([
[0,3],
[0,1],
[0,4],
[0,1],
[1,5],
[3,9],
[3,2],
[3,6],
[3,5],
[3,3]])

>> tf.py_function(distinct, [input], tf.int32)
<tf.Tensor: id=940, shape=(9, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1],
   [0, 3],
   [0, 4],
   [1, 5],
   [3, 2],
   [3, 3],
   [3, 5],
   [3, 6],
   [3, 9]], dtype=int32)>
```

**With Orders preserved**

```
def distinct_with_order_preserved(a):
    _a = a.numpy()
    return pd.DataFrame(_a).drop_duplicates().values

>> tf.py_function(distinct_with_order_preserved, [input], tf.int32)
<tf.Tensor: id=950, shape=(9, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 3],
   [0, 1],
   [0, 4],
   [1, 5],
   [3, 9],
   [3, 2],
   [3, 6],
   [3, 5],
   [3, 3]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: This is much better and simpler than the current accepted answer imo.

Comment: I don't think that this solution works. As stated in the answer itself, the output contains two copies of [0,1]. (I tested it myself just now to confirm that it actually does this.)

Comment: It works now, thanks. I did some performance testing of the non-order-preserving version on arrays of various sizes and levels of repetition. It looks like the tensorflow-only code in my answer runs in as much as 60% less time for small and for large arrays, while this (also much simpler, which is good) numpy approach ran in as much as 30% less time for some intermediate array sizes (~400-1000 input elements). YMMV based on hardware, but both approaches seem to have their uses.